# metallb ip address is not accessible when trying to connect from host machine, how to fix that?

Tags: kubernetes, virtualbox, bare-metal, k3s

I have installed k3s on ubuntu 23 machine, which is installed on virtualbox and with bridged network set.

My windows 10 host machine ip address

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2409:40f0:1128:8664:eb06:34c7:ed1e:fab9
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2409:40f0:1128:8664:346c:9b30:a91f:3e6b
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::568c:271a:f169:7312%19
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.165.117
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::44a7:67ff:fe01:cd76%19
                                       192.168.165.115
```

My IPaddress on virtualbox ubuntu 23 machine. --> 192.168.165.230

So I installed metallb on that k3s cluster by follwing below steps.

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.13.11/config/manifests/metallb-native.yaml
```

And the ipaddress pool added.

```
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: IPAddressPool
metadata:
  name: first-pool
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  addresses:
  #- 192.168.165.0/24
  - 192.168.165.240-192.168.165.250
---
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: L2Advertisement
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  ipAddressPools:
  - first-pool
```

below ipaddresses allocated to nginx services.

```
NAMESPACE        NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)                  AGE
default          kubernetes        ClusterIP      10.43.0.1       <none>            443/TCP                  7h33m
kube-system      kube-dns          ClusterIP      10.43.0.10      <none>            53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   7h33m
kube-system      metrics-server    ClusterIP      10.43.150.25    <none>            443/TCP                  7h33m
metallb-system   webhook-service   ClusterIP      10.43.121.158   <none>            443/TCP                  24m
testing          nginx             LoadBalancer   10.43.172.206   192.168.165.240   80:31210/TCP             168m
default          nginx             LoadBalancer   10.43.249.109   192.168.165.241   80:31548/TCP             29s
```

On the virtualbox ubuntu machine, I can access in firefox http://192.168.165.240 and http://192.168.165.241

But can't access them from my host machine.

How to fix that?